# Retrieve calibration data of decommisioned `ibmq` device without API token

Tags: ibm-q-experience

I would like to retrieve calibration data (preferably as .json or .rtf) for a `ibmq` device that has been decommissioned. Moreover, this was a device for which one needed an API token; one that I do not have access to.

Specifically, I would like to retrieve the calibration data for the `ibmq_montreal` device on the following dates (Y,m,d,h):

```
2021,11,28,06
2021,11,28,09
2021,11,27,23
2021,11,27,06
```

Is there any way to obtain this data?

Comment: You could try reaching out directly to IBM or one of the qiskit communication channels about this issue.